# For the EOS Online Subsystem, can my player sign up for an Epic Games account from the game, or does he/she have to do it from epicgames.com?

Tags: unreal-5, authentication

I am working on an Unreal Engine 5 game that would support Cloud Save functionality. I plan to use the Epic Online Services (EOS) Online Subsystem.

I plan to publish it on iOS and Android for now, and possibly Windows in the future.

I have a simple prototype that allows players to log in from the game. So when I do, I get the Sign In / Sign Up page. If I use my existing Epic Games account (I can connect through the linked Steam or Xbox Live Identity Providers), it logs me in. But I cannot sign up for a new account.

It gives me the following error message:

> "Application Access is Restricted"

> "Unfortunately, you do not have access to use this application."

Then I tried signing up from a web browser on epicgames.com, then using that new account to sign into my game, and it worked.

Is it possible to allow the player to perform the entire sign up and sign in process from the game, without forcing the user to visit epicgames.com?

Thanks.

Code:

```
void UCti2EosGameInstance::LoginWithEos(FString Id, FString Token, FString LoginType)
{
    UWorld* World = this->GetWorld();
    if (World == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    IOnlineSubsystem* SubsystemRef = Online::GetSubsystem(World);
    if (SubsystemRef == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    IOnlineIdentityPtr IdentityPointerRef = SubsystemRef->GetIdentityInterface();
    if (IdentityPointerRef == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    FOnlineAccountCredentials AccountDetails;
    AccountDetails.Id = Id;
    AccountDetails.Token = Token;
    AccountDetails.Type = LoginType;
    IdentityPointerRef->OnLoginCompleteDelegates->AddUObject(this, &UCti2EosGameInstance::LoginWithEos_Return);
    IdentityPointerRef->Login(0, AccountDetails);
}
```

Then from Blueprint when the "Login" button is called, I call this function and pass "accountportal" for LoginType, and empty strings elsewhere.